# Dynamically add buttons based on count in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add button with unique different id in for loop.
Like

```
<input id=1 type="submit" value="Remove" />
<input id=2 type="submit" value="Remove" />
<input id=3 type="submit" value="Remove" />
```

And so on

```
@{

using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Title)
        <input id={i} type="submit" value="Remove" />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@{

using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Title)
        <input id="@i" type="submit" value="Remove" />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,a small thing took lots of time.